# Visual Studio 2005 Design Mode Issue

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

In visual studio 2005 I created a website and implemented css. When I run the web site everything is working correctly, no problem with css.

But when I work in design mode css doesn't implemented on my page.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in WYSIWIG mode? If you're talking about before you run the code, just in the environment, what do you see, just your text?

I wouldn't rely on the WYSIWIG for accuracy; always test in the browser.